# Convert vbs to c# - Starting and Stop iis website and application pool

Tags: c#, vbscript, iis-6

Could anyone help me to get the code in c# for the below vbscript code.

```
Option Explicit

Dim WebSiteID, objWebSite, ObjAppPool

WebSiteID = "1"

Set objWebSite = GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/" & WebSiteID)
WScript.Echo "Stopping Web Site : " & objWebSite.ServerComment
objWebSite.Stop()

wscript.echo "Stopping Application Pool : " & objWebSite.AppPoolID
Set objAppPool = GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/" & objWebSite.AppPoolID)
objAppPool.Stop()

wscript.echo "Starting Application Pool : " & objWebSite.AppPoolID
objAppPool.Start()

WScript.Echo "Starting Web Site : " & objWebSite.ServerComment
objWebSite.Start()
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code translation service - have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop + Start = Recycle, so this should do:

Reference: System.DirectoryServices.dll

```
  using System.DirectoryServices;

  void Recycle(string appPool)
    {
        var appPoolPath = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/" + appPool;

        using (DirectoryEntry appPoolEntry = new DirectoryEntry(appPoolPath))
        {
            appPoolEntry.Invoke("Recycle", null);
            appPoolEntry.Close();
        }
    }
```

You might need to enable "IIS 6 WMI Compatibility" on the server if this method fails.